# Can I automatically link two cells using Google Apps Script, based on another matching cell condition?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm not a developer, so I apologise in advance for the way I'm about to write this out.

I have two spreadsheets: Spreadsheet 'A' and 'B.'

In Spreadsheet A, there are multiple tabs. A tab each for each relevant department. Spreadsheet B is used by a support team who assists the departments in Spreadsheet A, so they have their own sheet: all the information across Spreadsheet A automatically collated onto one tab.

However, there needs to be communication between the support team (B) and the other departments (A). I have a "Comments" column across both spreadsheet A and B for this, and I can set it up so that when it's updated on Spreadsheet B, it's automatically updated on Spreadsheet A. I'm trying to avoid people having to go through two spreadsheets if possible. I know there you can create a two-way link, so that when either spreadsheet is updated, the other is, too.

But what I'd prefer is for the spreadsheets to: automatically create a two-way link for the cells under the "Comments" column, between Spreadsheet A and B. This will happen when new rows are added (based on another matching cell in the same row). The other difficulty is that Spreadsheet A contains multiple tabs; is there a way to set up the code so it utilises an 'IFERROR' function? i.e., search for a matching cell between Spreadsheet A Tab 1 and Spreadsheet B Tab 1; if found, then create a two-way link; if not, then search in Spreadsheet A Tab 2 ... continuing until a match is found a link is created.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: How many people share each of these Spreadsheets?

Comment: Have you got any code that you've tried at all? Can you pleasepost what you've already given a go as well as sanitised copies of the spreadsheets that are involved?

Comment: @Cooper Between 50-100.